# Cost of a count statement for leaderboard ranking?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using mysql for a game. I have a scores table of approximately 150,000 records. The table looks like:

```
fk_user_id | high_score
```

The high_score column is an int. It has an index on it. I want to figure out a user's rank by running the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM scores WHERE high_score >= [x]
```

so supplying a user's current high_score to the above, I can get their rank. The idea would be that every time the user looks at a profile page, I would run the above to get the rank.

I'm wondering how expensive this is, and if I should even go down this path. Is mysql scanning the entire table every time the query is issued? Is this a crazy idea?

Update: Here's what 'explain' says about the query:

> id: 1
>
> select_type: SIMPLE
>
> table: scores
>
> type: range
>
> possible_keys: high_score
>
> key: high_score
>
> key_len: 5
>
> ref: null
>
> rows: 1
>
> extra: Using where; Using index

Thanks

Comment: can you run the following in mysql `explain SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM scores WHERE high_score >= [x]` and share the result in addition also `show indexes from scores` and add the results to your question.

Comment: Is the index on high_score for DESC order? It will probably render better performance.

Comment: @JosephB no the index is not in DESC order, I can look into doing that.

Comment: well the explain result shows to be good, and the col `high_score` is indexed so as long as as you use `= > < ` for comparison it should not do full table scan.

Comment: @user3203425 This is from MySQL 5.7 documentation "An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order." So, unfortunately, it won't make a difference currently. Basically, the rule of thumb is that you create the index in the most selective way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is scanning the entire table for every record you ask it to return.

Why use `count(*)` can't you use a `count(distinct User_ID)` or `count(user_ID)`

You should already have that column indexed, and i'm sure it would return your results accurately.

`SELECT COUNT(distinct user_ID) AS count FROM scores WHERE high_score >= [x]`

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I don't follow - could you show the full statement you're suggesting I switch to, given the table name + col names in the question?

Comment: Ok I tested and it works like you said. But why is it more efficient than using (\*)? Why would (\*) scan the whole table?

Comment: star is scanning the whole table due to it's selecting EVERYTHING in the tabl. You cannot select EVERYTHING without scanning everything. Then the aggregation returns. It may use the index of high_score, but it still may take a bit more time to return the other column. In this case, probably minimal, but that would be the only thing I can suggest for your particular scenario.

Comment: Your update to question ensures that you are using the high-score index so efficiency improvement is small if even noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

If `high_score` is index then cost is relatively small if not - then full table scan is made.

Relatively small - just read rowids from key and count them - very small cost.

You can always write  `explain` followed by query to check database exactly is doing for fetching your data.